# Waiting for chooser to open

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium

I have an app which i am trying to test using `Robotium Solo`

I have the solo object click on a button that is supposed to open a `chooser`..

How do I get solo to   wait for the `chooser` to appear ? as it seems I ask it to wait for 5 minutes, and the chooser only appears when the activity is finished and i exit back to the home screen.

How do I make it so that solo can click on an item in the chooser ?

this is part of the test method

```
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("not main activity", MainActivity.class);
        solo.clickOnButton("new");
        wait(300);
        solo.clickOnImageButton(0);
        solo.waitForDialogToOpen();
        solo.clickOnButton("Camera");
```

this is the wait method

```
private void wait(int seconds) {
        solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {

            @Override
            public boolean isSatisfied() {
                return false;
            }
        }, (int) (seconds * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS));
    }
```